# Not able to create a Firebase (Google)project after deleting the existing ones

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

[image: Check below error, when trying to create a new project]
I want to use Firebase Analytics. I had a existing project. But after deleting it I am not able to create a new project. Getting error saying maximum limit reached, when i dont even have single running project.

Comment: I think you'll have to contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) to resolve this.

Comment: Deleting a Firebase project will put them in a one-week "pending deletion" state, so that you can potentially restore them. You might be able to immediately delete them from the "projects pending deletion" list: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en. If that doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) so that they can look into it.

Comment: Thanks. @FrankvanPuffelen. I checked the next day, the error message changed with a link to https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en from where i could restore it. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 16):

**Max 8 Project created in free plan**

**Deleted Project available after 1 week**